# Installing QtWebengineView on Ubuntu: "A suitable version of dbus could not be found. QtWebEngine will not be built."

Tags: compiling, qt, dbus

I am trying to install QtWebEngineView on ubuntu with the proprietary codecs.

Running:

```
➜  qtwebengine git:(c3c37b4e) ✗ /usr/local/Qt-5.12.1/bin/qmake -r -Wall -- -proprietary-codecs -ffmpeg                               
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/configure.pri:94: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/configure.pri:94: Unescaped backslashes are deprecated

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... no
  Full debug information ................. no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
  Printing and PDF ....................... yes
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... yes
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. yes
  Use System Ninja ....................... yes
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ no
  Support qpa-xcb ........................ yes
  Use ALSA ............................... yes
  Use PulseAudio ......................... yes
  Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . yes
    opus ................................. yes
    ffmpeg ............................... yes
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    glib ................................. yes
    zlib ................................. yes
    minizip .............................. yes
    libevent ............................. yes
    jsoncpp .............................. yes
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. no
    lcms2 ................................ no
    png .................................. no
    JPEG ................................. no
    harfbuzz ............................. yes
    freetype ............................. no
  Required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... yes
    dbus ................................. no
    nss .................................. yes
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:
    x11 .................................. yes
    libdrm ............................... yes
    xcomposite ........................... yes
    xcursor .............................. yes
    xi ................................... yes
    xtst ................................. yes

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
Qt will be installed into '/usr/local/Qt-5.12.1'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.

WARNING: /usr/local/Qt-5.12.1/mkspecs/features/qt_parts.prf:17: Feature qt_build_config already included
WARNING: /usr/local/Qt-5.12.1/mkspecs/features/configure.prf:5: Feature configure_base already included
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/configure.prf:3: Feature functions already included
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/platform.prf:32: Excess colon in front of opening brace.
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/platform.prf:56: Excess colon in front of opening brace.
WARNING: /home/akiva/Programming/qt5/qtwebengine/mkspecs/features/platform.prf:168: Stray AND operator in front of AND operator.

A suitable version of dbus could not be found.
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

Dbus is installed, but how do I get the required version?
Do I need to update to 19.04?

Comment: Some reason you are not just doing `sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine` ? I am running it in 18.04.

Comment: @oldfred Does it ship with proprietary codecs? Namely, can you play youtube videos with h.264 in them? For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1c-z0x63Bk -- I am assuming no, because you need to recompile qt if you want your qtwebengine to include proprietary codecs. Even its installer doesn't offer you that option. Notice, `Proprietary Codecs ..................... yes` in the op. This is the whole reason I am going through this rigamarole.

Comment: I am just looking up stocks, but copied & pasted your youtube link into my little program and ran. `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView` & 
`from httpWidget5 import Ui_HttpWidget` Where Ui_HttpWidget is my own UI.

Comment: @oldfred and the page loaded? That would be interesting.

Comment: Page loaded & video played. Perhaps because I also have Chromium installed & that added other codecs? Not idea otherwise.

Comment: @oldfred hm. This information could be useful, I'll get back to you on this.